# Display state of progress bar component based on array length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, ecmascript-6

EDIT:

I have tried

```
 <ProgressBar percentage={(percentage / 100) * questions.length} />
```

but the progress is not being updated equally

I have a basic functional component for my progress bar that looks like this

```
const ProgressBar = props => {
  const { percentage } = props
  return (
    <div className="progress-bar">
      <Filler percentage={percentage} />
    </div>
  )
}

const Filler = props => {
  const { percentage } = props
  return <div className="filler" style={{ width: `${percentage}%` }} />
}

export default ProgressBar
```

Which I import into the main component like this

```
this.state = {
      percentage: 0,
    }
```

The state of my progress bar is updated through a handle click function

```
selectAnswer = answer => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      percentage: state.percentage + 20,
      currentQuestionId: state.currentQuestionId + 1,
    }))
  }
```

My progress bar is fully functional right now, the state gets updated each time the user moves to the next question.

I'd like the state of progress bar to be updated dynamically, showing its current state based on an array..

```
questions object
    0: {id: 1, text: "What is your favourite number?", type: "multiChoice", choices: Array(3)}
    1: {id: 2, text: "What is your favourite colour?", type: "multiChoice", choices: Array(3)}
    2: {id: 3, text: "Which workshop would you prefer?", type: "cardChoice", choices: Array(2)}
    3: {id: 4, text: "Rank your favourite movie from Top to Bottom", type: "rankChoice", choices: Array(5)}
    4: {id: 5, text: "The end.", type: "end"}
```

For example if currentQuestionId === 2 , this.state.percentage would reflect that, or if currentQuestionId === 5, this state.percentage would be 100

Comment: You can multiply `currentQuestionId` by 20 or by 100 divided by the number of questions.

Comment: currentQuestionId just let's the app know which question to display, shouldn't I divide percentage by the number of questions instead?

Comment: What I meant is you can multiply `currentQuestionId` by 20 or you can multiply `currentQuestionId` by (100 divided by the number of questions).

Comment: @Yousername Where should I be doing that?

Comment: Inside your selectAnswer, or wherever you think is best.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing the calculation in ProgressBar props for now